# Having multiple statements on where clause with same column name

Tags: mysql

I have a sample SQL statement that says:

```
SELECT * from users WHERE id = 2 OR id = 5 OR id = 7
```

What I would like is to avoid repeating `id` each time in the `where` clause. Is there a shortcut for this in MySQL that will allow me to mention the `id` only once?

Comment: You are looking for `IN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the IN clause

```
SELECT * from users WHERE id IN(2,5,7);
```

if these Ids you are using in the comparison come from another table you can even do

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE id in (SELECT other_id FROM other_table WHERE somecondition)
```

Comment: ok that is what i am looking for. thanks. additionally, is  there a reverse for IN?

Comment: Did you mean `NOT IN` yes such a clause is available.

Comment: You can also do `select * from users where 'steve' IN (users.fname, users.lname)`

Comment: yes @CptMisery that's a nice trick thats often overlooked. post your own answer and add that. Will get my upvote

Comment: thank you @VoltaireJohnSecondesBiton you've got mine too

Answer (score 2):

e4c5 gave you the answer you needed, but here is something else you can do with `IN`:

`select * from users where 'steve' IN (users.fname, users.lname)`